# Compiling Rinside with g++ in Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, rinside

I wish to compile Rinside in Mac OS X 10.9. I have Xcode 5.

I've downloaded the latest version of Rcpp and RInside (2014) and when I wanted to install them with the following commands:

sudo R CMD INSTALL ~/Downloads/Rcpp_0.11.0.tar.gz

I received the following Error:

- installing to library ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library’
- installing *source* package ‘Rcpp’ ...
  ** libs
  llvm-g++-4.2 -arch x86_64 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/ -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c Date.cpp -o Date.o
  make: llvm-g++-4.2: No such file or directory
  make: *** [Date.o] Error 1
  ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rcpp’
- removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/Rcpp’

I appreciate any comments.

Comment: Why does it seem to be just for Linux? Do you get an error that claims that it is?

Comment: I have just changed the question. I think the main reason is Xcode 5 does not support llvm-g++-4.2. I don't know how I should install Rcpp and Rinside without that.

Comment: This has been discussed *a lot* of time since the release of Mavericks. Look on StackOverflow (use the search box above with something like '[r] os x mavericks') and/or on the r-sig-mac list.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I tried compiling RInside from source on Mavericks but I ran into `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64` and `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)` and `make: *** [rinside_callbacks0] Error 1`  Note that I have all the required headers and followed the correct installation and make instructions completely.  Is this an incompatibility with OSX Mavericks?  If yes, then why is there an identical incompatibility with OSX Mountain Lion?  I tried doing identical things on both operating system versions...

Answer (score 0):

For an illustrative example of how to get Xcode to compile RInside code, see https://youtu.be/sjiSaaNA8BY

You have to install R first.  Launch R and install.package "Rcpp" and "RInstall" (from R).  The video describes the steps needed to compile rinside_sample3.cpp from examples/standard folder in the zip file at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RInside/index.html.